# create a custom video player

Tags: javascript, video

I am interested in creating a custom video player, for online usage in my website. the reason I want the video player is because, I want the user to click on the time bar and allow him to choose "time segments" (having a start and stop point) and being able to drag them around.
what language is more approppriate for this kind of work? javascript?

Comment: Could you define time segments further? Do you mean like chapters?

Comment: let the user choose betwwen let's say 00:14 and 00:56.you can say "user - defined chapters" :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use the adobe's [StrobeMediaPlayback](http://osmf.org/strobe_mediaplayback.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a javascript/html5 player http://videojs.com/